# How to center a form after programmatically switching screens

Tags: c#, winforms

Given a `Form` I want to center the form after switching screens.  How can I accomplish the task?

```
 internal static void SetFormToBiggestMonitor(Form form, bool center = true)
    {
        Screen biggestScreen = FindBiggestMonitor();//assume this works
        form.Location = biggestScreen.Bounds.Location;

        if (center)
        {
            form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why not form.CenterToScreen()?

Comment: nevermind, msdn says it's not to be called directly from code

Comment: @BryanJ - Yea, I saw a SO question with that as the answer...but then MSDN said don't use it so yea....

Comment: Not sure what the question is about.  The standard mistake is to put this in the constructor instead of in OnLoad().  The form can be rescaled or the user's preferences for the title bar height may not match yours.  The true size isn't set until all this is sorted out, at the Load event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One not so loopy way to accomplish the task...

```
    private static Point CenterForm(Form form, Screen screen)
    {
        return new Point(
                         screen.Bounds.Location.X + (screen.WorkingArea.Width - form.Width) / 2,
                         screen.Bounds.Location.Y + (screen.WorkingArea.Height - form.Height) / 2
                         );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for the offset of the monitor before setting the position, but other than that, it should be fairly simple.

```
if (center)
{
      form.Location = new Point
      (
         biggestScreen.WorkingArea.X + ((biggestScreen.WorkingArea.Width + form.Width)/2),
         biggestScreen.WorkingArea.Y + ((biggestScreen.WorkingArea.Height + form.Height)/2)
      );
}
```

But [Form.CenterToScreen()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.centertoscreen.aspx) should work just fine, but apparently Microsoft doesn't recommend using it? Not sure why.

Comment: I'm sure they don't allow calling `CenterToScreen()` because it directly deals with unmanaged code (HWND)...per the remarks.

Comment: I understand that, but it does work (just checked). What I question is why they would include it as a public method in the Form properties if they didn't expect it to be used. That's all.

Comment: But just setting the location and make sure to account for the monitors offset positioning when dealing with multi-monitors. If you don't, you'll always be setting the position in reference to the primary monitor. And that's often a problem when developers don't take that into account.

Comment: Hm.  What version of .NET you using?  In .NET 4.0 it's protected not public.  I can't get to it at all.  Short of maybe doing some reflection hackery.

Comment: I'm currently using .NET 4.0. Applied to a button click, I just added this.CenterToScreen(); and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What if instead of all these calculations, you just use [Form.CenterToScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.centertoscreen.aspx)

```
this.CenterToScreen();
```